# Apache Pulsar disk usage in a container

Tags: diskspace, apache-pulsar, pulsar

I am running Apache pulsar in a Docker container in `standalone` mode.

I am publishing log file lines into the pulsar topic. The total logs are about 60G in size.

The pulsar  container keeps running out of disk space on the `/` disk and has to terminate.

It is a default configuration. The docker-compose file looks as follows

```
  pulsar:
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar
    container_name: pulsar
    command: bin/pulsar standalone
    ports:
        - 6650:6650
        - 8080:8080
```

Is there a way to limit pulsar disk usage so that it does not run out of all the space ?

Comment: set a volume to outside the container?

Answer (score 3):

Apache Pulsar allows to specify [retention policies and expiry](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/cookbooks-retention-expiry/) for a namespace.

To specify a retention policy, you can use the Pulsar admin CLI:

```
bin/pulsar-admin namespaces set-retention my-tenant/my-namespace --size 10G --time 1d
```

Another way is to execute a POST request to the Pulsar REST API:

```
localhost:8080/admin/v2/namespaces/my-tenant/my-namespace/retention
```

where the body has the following JSON structure:

```
{
    "retentionTimeInMinutes": 1440,
    "retentionSizeInMB": 10240
}
```

Update the commands above with your values for *my-tenant, my-namespace, localhost*